# Does a loop with Task.Delay() create a memory leak?

Tags: c#, task, async-await

I am implementing an asynchronous buffer system where I want exactly one consumer of a queue to guarantee that items are processes in order. The consumer should check the queue periodically, process all items in it, and then "Sleep" for some interval. Task.Delay() seems perfect for such a system, since unlike Thread.Sleep() it won't consume a thread while sleeping and unlike Timer it won't launch a new thread if processing the queue items takes longer than the sleep interval. However, I'm wondering if using Task.Delay() in a while loop will create a memory leak if the task system is tracking the entire continuation list for the original task. For reference, my system looks like:

```
void EnqueueItem(Item item) {
    lock (this._lock) { this._items.Add(item); }
}

async Task Consumer() {
    while (true) {
        await Task.Delay(interval).ConfigureAwait(false);

        Item[] items = null;
        lock (this._lock) {
            if (this._disposed) { return; }
            if (this._items.Count > 0)
            {
                items = this._items.ToArray();
                this._items.Clear();
            }
        }
        if (items != null) { Process(items); }
    }
}

// in the constructor of the buffer
this.Consumer();
```

Comment: I've previously used the timer method and just use the `Monitor.TryEnter` method. If it can't get a lock it can just exit the method without doing anything. This means a thread might be created but it won't be around for long. Alternatively you can stop and start the timer at the beginning and end of each process loop.

Comment: A task's continuation list is automatically garbage collected once the task completes and your code drops the Task object reference.  Task.Delay has no effect on this, other than keeping the task running longer than perhaps necessary.

Comment: Not related to your question, but if you're calling `Consumer()` from the constructor, what happens when `Process()` throws an exception?

Comment: @svick in the real code, the Process() call is wrapped in a try-catch for exactly this reason (the error is logged in the catch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't cause a memory leak, however if you are in a tight loop you *may* want to dispose the tasks rather than waiting for their finalizer

e.g.

```
var t = Task.Delay(interval);
await t.ConfigureAwait(false);
t.Dispose();
```

But you probably don't want to, and shouldn't need to (see [Do I need to dispose of Tasks?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/) )

Comment: that link is a 403 for me

Answer (score 8):

> I am implementing an asynchronous buffer system...

I strongly suggest you use an existing one. [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is my top recommendation. But if that's not available on your platform, then [my `AsyncProducerConsumerQueue`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncProducerConsumerQueue) is an option.

This setup allows your consumer to just use `ReceiveAsync`/`DequeueAsync` and no `Task.Delay` is necessary.

That said, I don't believe there would be a memory leak like the one you describe. I have not actually run it in a profiler to verify this, though.

Comment: Would you mind posting an example using TPL Dataflow? In this case, I am enqueueing a very large number of items which the single poller periodically processes in batch (I want the delay so that a bunch of items can build up). That's why I'm not using things like BlockingCollection which focus on enqueuing/dequeuing 1 object at a time.

Comment: OK; I wasn't aware of the batching requirements. In that case, you almost definitely want to use Reactive Extensions. They have built-in operations that can batch based on a time interval.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion As an alternative to Rx, you could use `BatchBlock` and call its `TriggerBatch()` from a timer. Or, if the batching should be controlled by the speed of the consumer, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20697649/41071).

Answer (score 0):

No not if you await the `Task.Delay()`.
Yes, if the task is not awaited

```
[Test]
public async Task TaskDelay()
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        var t = Task.Delay(i);
        await Task.WhenAny(t, NoOp());
    }
}
public async Task NoOp()
{
    await Task.Yield();
}
```

Will leak memory.

A cancellation token needs to be passed to `Task.Delay` and it needs to be cancelled to stop the leak e.g. this will not leak

```
public async Task TaskDelay()
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var t = Task.Delay(i, cts.Token);
        await Task.WhenAny(t, NoOp());
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```