# Doing await Task.Delay in an infinite loop

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I have the below code, which will execute `Action operation`, if an exception occurs in it, it will be retried.

Because the code `await Task.Delay(delay);` is within the `while(true)`, I'm hesitating if this will cause any memory leaks? Like creation of infinite `threads`?

This code works fine, but I'm only worried about a possible memory leakage? If anyone can share some insight, I'll appreciate it.

```
public class OperationWithBasicRetry
{
  public async Task StartOperationAsync(Action operation, TimeSpan delay, int retryCount)
  {
    int currentRetry = 0;

    while(true)
    {
      try
      {
        operation();

        // Success
        break;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        if (++currentRetry > retryCount)
        {
          throw;
        }
      }

      await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: there is no such thing as infinite tasks, your process will end up by crashing (with no exception thrown) before reaching int.MaxValue because of a heap overflow

Comment: How would you run infinite tasks if you have an `int` check? At most, you would be creating `int.MaxValue` tasks

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri why? This isn't a totally unreasonable suggestion. You'd might create a similar loop when implementing `IHostedService` in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: You can use `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)` to wait indefinitely.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski `Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan` is the same, but is more descriptive.

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri no, this will not crash.

Comment: @canton7 The value of this field is -00:00:00.0010000, or -1 millisecond, that's the same)

Comment: I'm stress testing right now, and I don't see any increment in memory usage.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski hence my comment of "is the same, but is more descriptive"

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski And who said the OP wants to wait indefinitely? The OP correctly waits for a parametrisized number of milliseconds

Comment: I don't want to wait indefinitely. I want to retry indefinitely.

Comment: @CharlesMager cause the while() will create an infinite return address. check this out https://www.quora.com/Why-does-an-infinite-recursive-program-give-a-stack-overflow-segmentation-fault-but-an-infinite-while-for-loop-will-not

Comment: @canton7 let it run for 4 hours and it will.

Comment: No, this is not recursive.

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri your link explains why this *wouldn't* overflow. This is a while loop, it's not recursive.

Comment: Also remember that this is an `async` method, and so the compiler chops it up and turns it into a state machine. The final result doesn't have any loops in it at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a loop with Task.Delay() create a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705025/does-a-loop-with-task-delay-create-a-memory-leak)

Comment: Also, remember that async/await does not always result in a new thread. You will also find that a console app does not have a special UI thread, as winforms or WPF, and if there is a need for threads, they are scheduled using the default thread pool. This code should not "starve" threads. (Unless operation(); does). Check these articles, they might do a better job at explaining the concept: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea thank you so much for those links, great read!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is safe.

This is an `async` method, and so the compiler chops it up and turns it into a state machine. As a very very rough approximation to illustrate the point, you can think about the compiled code as looking a little bit like this:

```
private class State
{
    public int currentRetry;
    public Action operation;
    public TimeSpan delay;
    public int retryCount;
    public TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs;

    private void StartOperationAsyncImpl(object unused)
    {
        try
        {
            operation();
            tcs.SetResult(null);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (++currentRetry > retryCount)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }
        }

        // I'm ignoring the delay bit, because it has no affect on the point
        // I'm trying to make.
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StateOperationAsyncImpl);
    }
}

public Task StartOperationAsync(Action operation, TimeSpan delay, int retryCount)
{
    State state = new State();
    state.currentRetry = 0;
    state.operation = operation;
    state.delay = delay;
    state.retryCount = retryCount;
    state.tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state.StartOperationAsyncImpl);

    return state.tcs;
}
```

Of course, the actual compiled code looks nothing like this ([it looks like this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAocVoFYHIMxQEwQHkAHAUwCcBDAFwEsB7AOwHUaqALAIQoGcaBjAEokqZAJ5IA3kghQcIABxQAbBADKVCmSrFy1egwCC3UQz4AKGPjqlKtRgBoIAFRoBbEqqIUGEACYkAGwpRRxoGKggyYTEAYToAV3CASmkIKUQZGTCIvniyKPChEVEIAF4IMExUmQB3NhoAkjMReJIUjMz0zMzi6s6+7utdOwYzJKqO7pkAemm1eL4+Em5uAcyAIyiKAGtMKYgAXzW+aj42CDMAUQAPJaIRiBJr9v2u/YgaADMLgGof3PyJEK0RKAD5IiC4okqC93m93hB2GQ6DU9u8jpNMhi1iAAJzKAB0ABFAsEzP4gqJxn0MTIMQcgA==)), but it illustrates my point.

There's no recursion going on here. There's not even an infinite loop. You've got a method which, when called, tries to do your operation. If it fails, then it queues itself onto the ThreadPool and returns. That call to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` returns straight away, and it doesn't wait until the work has been completed.

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` also doesn't create new threads - it queues the work to be executed by a pool of pre-existing threads.

(Before someone comments - I know that the actual compiled code won't use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` directly, but it will probably use the default TaskScheduler, which calls `ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem` internally, so it's a good approximation).

Answer (score 0):

I think it will not as it either exits the loop via break or via throw once the `retryCount` condition is met. Depending on your `retryCount` that shall be way before causing the memory leak.

Comment: But I'm planning to also have a method which will retry infinitely.